# How to interpret the very rich iPhone analytics data about battery use / health?

Tags: iphone, battery

On [my quest to scrutinize an iPhone 11 here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458940/iphone-11-battery-health-can-be-fudged-to-100-very-easily-right) and over [on the electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/663791/why-isnt-it-easy-to-put-an-ampere-meter-into-any-battery-driven-electronics/663799), which iPhone 11 was sold to me supposedly with a 100% new and original replacement battery, I am digging in deeper. Found [a youtuber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBqSGUDOPOI) who, although wrong about his method to calculate battery health, nevertheless showed a treasure trove of data in the cumulative analytics file. There is tons of data about battery. Here it is for my case:

```
{
  "deviceId": "b754f...8173d",
  "message": {
    "Count": 1,
    "last_value_AlgoChemID": 1005802730,
    "last_value_AppleRawMaxCapacity": 2592,
    "last_value_CycleCount": 1069,
    "last_value_GasGaugeFirmwareVersion": 109050658,
    "last_value_LifetimeUPOCount": 0,
    "last_value_MaximumCapacityPercent": 103,
    "last_value_MaximumFCC": 3323,
    "last_value_MaximumQmax": 3385,
    "last_value_MinimumFCC": 624,
    "last_value_MinimumQmax": 2611,
    "last_value_NCCMax": 3239,
    "last_value_NCCMin": 2192,
    "last_value_NominalChargeCapacity": 2475,
    "last_value_Qmax": 2903,
    "last_value_Ra00": 408,
    "last_value_Ra01": 350,
    "last_value_Ra02": 299,
    "last_value_Ra03": 240,
    "last_value_Ra04": 243,
    "last_value_Ra05": 211,
    "last_value_Ra06": 215,
    "last_value_Ra07": 278,
    "last_value_Ra08": 309,
    "last_value_Ra09": 345,
    "last_value_Ra10": 406,
    "last_value_Ra11": 386,
    "last_value_Ra12": 502,
    "last_value_Ra13": 795,
    "last_value_Ra14": 1615,
    "last_value_TotalOperatingTime": 30868,
    "last_value_WeightedRa": 274,
    "last_value_batteryServiceFlags": 3,
    "last_value_epoch": 1682104245
  },
  "name": "AzulE_Battery_Calibration_Baseline",
  "sampling": 100,
  "uuid": "2a9464d6-....-....-....-03067956a435_3"
}
```

There is tons of data here which could be really interesting. For now what I find most directly and easy to interpret might be:

```
"last_value_AppleRawMaxCapacity": 2592,
```

if this is actually 2592 mAh, then it is 83% of the 3110 mAh that it should have.

That is not great. And if

```
"last_value_TotalOperatingTime": 30868,
```

means days, then it would be 3.5 years of operating time. How a phone that is outwardly in such pristine condition could have amassed such long operating time is quite surprising to me.

But I want to be a little bit more careful in the interpretation of all of this.

What would this show if the battery had been replaced? Let's say that the hours just keep on counting, in that case the 3.5 years are on the device (surprising for the pristine cosmetic state it is in), the time on the battery could be much less. What is it?

Also the denominator for my % calculation might be lower than 3110. For example, there is this line:

```
"last_value_NominalChargeCapacity": 2475,
```

what "nominal" means in my book is what it should be, something assumed, not measured. So in that case I would be 2592/2475 = 104% battery health. But in the worst case it is 2475/3110 = 79.6%. Which is it?

Am I clasping for straw when I take this

```
"last_value_MaximumCapacityPercent": 103,
```

to mean that my more optimistic interpretation is actually true? This is also mentioned on a [reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/ipad/comments/10r5mr2/psa_check_battery_health_and_cycles_without_any/). But on this discussion someone says that the denominator should be

```
"last_value_MaximumFCC": 3323,
```

which, he claims, "is the actual capacity your iPad's battery had when it was manufactured". In that case I would be even worse, with 2475 / 3323 = 74.5%. Ugh! But if it's this bad, why is last_value_MaximumCapacityPercent saying 103?

There is a lot more data here, which I think is an excellent source of information and it might not be as widely known. I appreciate if someone could explain more or point to the definite source of interpreting all this interesting data!

Something interesting would be if those who respond could look up their own file and say how the settings app's battery health % compares with the various alternative modes of calculating it from this awesome analytics data.

BTW, there is, of course, no shortage of opinions about these things on the internet. But even [people who seem to speak with authority](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6--6z4ZcNk), will not explain the full picture, and I think only those who can explain *all* those numbers can be sure to really understand *each one* of them.

---

Here is another battery related thing from a different analytics file. Notice this has a

```
"last_value_BatteryHealthMetric": 274,
```

wouldn't it be great if someone knew what this means?

```
{
  "deviceId": "b75...3d",
  "message": {
    "Count": 15,
    "last_value_AlgoChemID": 1005802730,
    "last_value_AppleRawMaxCapacity": 2592,
    "last_value_AverageTemperature": 26,
    "last_value_BatteryHealthMetric": 274,
    "last_value_BatterySerialChanged": false,
    "last_value_ChemID": 1005801232,
    "last_value_ChemicalWeightedRa": 290,
    "last_value_CycleCount": 1070,
    "last_value_CycleCountLastQmax": 46,
    "last_value_DailyMaxSoc": 99,
    "last_value_DailyMinSoc": 99,
    "last_value_Flags": 8321,
    "last_value_FlashWriteCount": null,
    "last_value_GGUpdateStatus": null,
    "last_value_GasGaugeFirmwareVersion": 109050658,
    "last_value_HighAvgCurrentLastRun": null,
    "last_value_ITMiscStatus": 7187,
    "last_value_KioskModeHighSocDays": 0,
    "last_value_KioskModeHighSocSeconds": 22,
    "last_value_KioskModeLastHighSocHours": 0,
    "last_value_LastResetReason": 4,
    "last_value_LastUPOTimestamp": 0,
    "last_value_LifetimeUPOCount": 0,
    "last_value_LowAvgCurrentLastRun": null,
    "last_value_MaximumCapacityPercent": 103,
    "last_value_MaximumChargeCurrent": 3520,
    "last_value_MaximumDeltaVoltage": null,
    "last_value_MaximumDischargeCurrent": -4302,
    "last_value_MaximumFCC": 3323,
    "last_value_MaximumOverChargedCapacity": null,
    "last_value_MaximumOverDischargedCapacity": null,
    "last_value_MaximumPackVoltage": 4450,
    "last_value_MaximumQmax": 3385,
    "last_value_MaximumRa0_8": null,
    "last_value_MaximumRa8": null,
    "last_value_MaximumTemperature": 532,
    "last_value_MinimumDeltaVoltage": null,
    "last_value_MinimumFCC": 624,
    "last_value_MinimumPackVoltage": 2531,
    "last_value_MinimumQmax": 2611,
    "last_value_MinimumRa0_8": null,
    "last_value_MinimumRa8": null,
    "last_value_MinimumTemperature": 7,
    "last_value_NCCMax": 3239,
    "last_value_NCCMin": 2192,
    "last_value_NominalChargeCapacity": 2483,
    "last_value_OriginalBattery": null,
    "last_value_QmaxCell0": 2912,
    "last_value_QmaxUpdFailCount": null,
    "last_value_QmaxUpdSuccessCount": null,
    "last_value_RDISCnt": null,
    "last_value_RSS": 304,
    "last_value_RaTable_1": 408,
    "last_value_RaTable_10": 345,
    "last_value_RaTable_11": 406,
    "last_value_RaTable_12": 386,
    "last_value_RaTable_13": 502,
    "last_value_RaTable_14": 795,
    "last_value_RaTable_15": 1615,
    "last_value_RaTable_2": 350,
    "last_value_RaTable_3": 299,
    "last_value_RaTable_4": 240,
    "last_value_RaTable_5": 243,
    "last_value_RaTable_6": 211,
    "last_value_RaTable_7": 215,
    "last_value_RaTable_8": 278,
    "last_value_RaTable_9": 309,
    "last_value_ResetCnt": 0,
    "last_value_ResetDataComms": 0,
    "last_value_ResetDataCorruption": null,
    "last_value_ResetDataFirmware": 3,
    "last_value_ResetDataHardFault": null,
    "last_value_ResetDataHardware": 3,
    "last_value_ResetDataSoftware": 0,
    "last_value_ResetDataSwWatchDog": null,
    "last_value_ResetDataWatchDog": 0,
    "last_value_ServiceOption": 9,
    "last_value_TemperatureSamples": 111193707,
    "last_value_TimeAbove95Perc": null,
    "last_value_TotalOperatingTime": 30887,
    "last_value_UpdateTime": 1682170516,
    "last_value_WeekMfd": 939,
    "last_value_WeightedRa": 290,
    "last_value_Wom_1": 3486521,
    "last_value_Wom_2": null,
    "last_value_batteryServiceFlags": 2147483651,
    "last_value_calibrationFlags": 1280,
    "last_value_xFlags": 84
  },
  "name": "BatteryConfigValueHistogramFinal_WithAllResetCounters",
  "sampling": 100,
  "uuid": "a8da5d88-....-....-....-0150f967a944_3"
}
```

Comment: Here are some articles about the science of batteries which may provide you with some background on the chemistry and physics behind energy storage: [Argonne National Laborary](https://www.anl.gov/science-101/batteries), lithium ion batteries explained by the US [Department of Energy](https://www.anl.gov/science-101/batteries), and most importantly, Apple's [iPhone Battery and performance](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208387) page. Tetsujin's answer to your original question is the best one so far. Batteries age, even when not in use. Replacement batteries take some time to calibrate.

Comment: How can you even get your battery health over 100%? That's not possible. Unfortunately, it's probably the other result.

Comment: @Thinkr, that value is possible because those values are sourced from the battery control chip.  The max capacity is hard coded into the chip, but if a battery was swapped that outputs a higher value, the *calculation* will be over 100.

Comment: @Allan Oh alright.